# How to Select XML Nodes with XML Namespaces with C#

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces

I have to analyze a XML doc with special namespace using C#, and I get some idea from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633127/how-to-select-xml-nodes-with-xml-namespaces-from-an-xmldocument). But my code fail to get the expected XML node, because the XML structure is very special...

There is a namespace in root node in XML

```
<MDOC xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com/PSS/PSS_Survey01">
```

Here is my code to get this root node

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(path);

        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("urn", "schemas-microsoft-com/PSS/PSS_Survey01");

        XmlNode root = doc.SelectSingleNode("MDOC", nsmgr);
```

Help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what is special about your XML structure.

I would write the code little differently

```
string xmlNamespace = String.Empty;
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr;
XmlNodeList nodeInfo = FABRequestXML.GetElementsByTagName("RootNodeName");
xmlNamespace = Convert.ToString(nodeInfo[0].Attributes["xmlns"].Value);
nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(MyXml.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("AB", xmlNamespace);

XmlNode myNode = MyXml.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("AB:NodeName", nsmgr);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Awesome, this works fine. The special structure I mean is some xml node with a default namespace. And I get a deep understanding about this from another post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271689/xml-selectnodes-with-default-namespace-via-xmlnamespacemanager-not-working-as-ex