# Dealing with NameSpace while reading XML Doc

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

Ok, here is my issue, i have some code which was written to downlaod an File from an FTP server and then process the XML file. All good for a long time but now the XML file has a Namespace and my code no longer works. Here is the code in question which finds all call nodes and then processes them

```
    Public Shared Function ParseXMLAndSave(ByVal xmlContent As String) As Generic.List(Of CallDetailRecordDataType)

    Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument
    Try
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlContent)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Failed to load xml content. " & ex.Message)
    End Try

    Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("File/CDRs/Call")
    If nodes.Count = 0 Then Throw New Exception("No data node [File/CDRs/Call] found")

    Dim list As New Generic.List(Of CallDetailRecordDataType)

    For temp As Integer = 0 To nodes.Count - 1
        Try
            Dim record As CallDetailRecordDataType = ParseMainNode(nodes(temp))
            list.Add(record)
            SaveCallRecord(record)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Trace.WriteLine("Failed to parse node. " & ex.Message)
        End Try

    Next

    Return list
End Function
```

So what do i need to do to be able to use to find those nodes again after my xml file has now a NameSpace ?

The Namespace looks like this in the XML Doc

```
<File xmlns="http://www.metaswitch.com/cfs/billing/V1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" compatibility="2">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [How to Select XML Nodes with XML Namespaces from an XmlDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633127/how-to-select-xml-nodes-with-xml-namespaces-from-an-xmldocument)

For your case the code should be like this. However without your xml document I haven't been able to validate this.

```
    Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument
    Try
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlContent)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Failed to load xml content. " & ex.Message)
    End Try

    'Create a namespace manager
    Dim nsmgr As New XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable)
    'Add a default namespace.
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("", "http://www.metaswitch.com/cfs/billing/V1.0")

    'Pass the namespaces into the query
    Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("File/CDRs/Call", nsmgr)
    If nodes.Count = 0 Then Throw New Exception("No data node [File/CDRs/Call] found")
```